# How can i use dynamic student list in a from and insert data into database

Tags: php, loops, dynamic, insert

I'm new to php and have been struggling for days trying to find an answer. I have a list of student that has been dynamically created using a while loop inside of a form. I've then added an input box so that I can submit there grades. This works well.

```
<form action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" name="assignments" id="assignments">
<?php

while($row_students = mysql_fetch_array($students))
{ ?>
    <input grade="grade[]" type="text" size="3" />
    <? echo $row_students['student_number'];?> 
    <input name="student_id[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $row_students['student_number']; ?>" /> 

    <? echo $row_students['student_name'] ; ?>
    <input name="assignment_name[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $row_assignments['assignment_name'];?>" /><br/>
    <? }

?>
<br/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
| <a href="index.php">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

When I print_r the post data I get:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => assignment 1
        [1] => assignment 1
        [2] => assignment 1
        [3] => assignment 1
        [4] => assignment 1
        [5] => assignment 1
        [6] => assignment 1
        [7] => assignment 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 432100312
        [1] => 432100351
        [2] => 432100353
        [3] => 432100354
        [4] => 432100355
        [5] => 433536343
        [6] => 436253636
        [7] => 473634728
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 21
        [1] => 21
        [2] => 33
        [3] => 42
        [4] => 15
        [5] => 26
        [6] => 37
        [7] => 18
    )
```

)

My problem is now two fold.  I think that it should display like this:

```
[0] => Array
(
[0] => assignment 1
[0] => 432100312
[0] => 21
)
```

as I want to use this data to insert each set into the database which has the following fields - assignment_name, student_id and _grade.

I've also tried several insert loops to no avail hence this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will work for you without any issues:

```
<form action="assignments.php" method="POST" name="assignments" id="assignments">
<?php
$key = 0;
while($row_students = mysql_fetch_array($students))
{ ?>
    <input name="student[<? echo $key ?>][grade]" type="text" size="3" value=""/>
    <? echo $row_students['student_number'];?> 
    <input name="student[<? echo $key ?>][student_id]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $row_students['student_number']; ?>" /> 

    <? echo $row_students['student_name'] ; ?>
    <input name="student[<? echo $key ?>][assignment_name]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $row_assignments['assignment_name'];?>" /><br/>
    <? $key++;}

?>
<br/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
| <a href="index.php">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

This code will generate the array you wanted.

Comment: Thanks All and VJ this one was exactly what i needed so it return the arrays as needed. last part is how do i now wrap my results into an insert query.

Comment: Use this code as an example:

$sql = array(); 
foreach( $_POST['student'] as $row ) {
    $sql[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['grade']).'", '.mysql_real_escape_string($row['student_number']).", '.mysql_real_escape_string($row['assignment_name']).')';
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (grade, student_number, assignment_name) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));

Comment: Hi thanks but i couldn't get it to work , i tried this: `code`if(!empty($_POST['submit'])){ 
 
 $sql = array(); 
 foreach( $_POST['student'] as $row ) { 
 $sql[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['grade']).', 
          '.mysql_real_escape_string($row['student_id']).', 
    '.mysql_real_escape_string($row['assignment_name']).'
    ")'; } 
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO graded_assignment (grade, student_number, assignment_name) 
    VALUES '.implode(',', $sql)); 
   confirm_query($sql);
} it doesn't populate the db or return any errors

Comment: Write if($_POST['submit']) instead of if(!empty($_POST['submit'])).

echo the code before you actually insert into the database:

echo 'INSERT INTO graded_assignment (grade, student_number, assignment_name) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql);

Now copy the printed query and put it in the database directly and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks again I finally got it working. had to adapt the query for the db. good advice echoing the query. thanks

Comment: Glad my answers helped you. Don't forget to vote and choose my answer as best (if you agree).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
$arrNew = array();
  foreach ($arr as $value) {
      foreach ($value as $key=>$value) {
          $arrNew[$key][] = $value;
       }
  }
```

consider $arr is your base array

Comment: You did not provide the html part

Answer (score 0):

just taking a wild guess here but i believe I did something similar a while back. 
below will print_r like follows :
Array ( [student] => Array ( ['name'] => dfsdfsdf ['id'] => 3 ['so'] => 4 ) )

```
<form method="post" action"#">
    <input name="student['name']" type="text" size="3" />
    <input name="student['id']" type="hidden" value="3" /> 
    <input name="student['so']" type="hidden" value="4" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

in your case

```
<form action="assignments.php" method="POST" name="assignments" id="assignments">
<?php

while($row_students = mysql_fetch_array($students))
{ ?>
    <input name="student['grade']" type="text" size="3" />
    <? echo $row_students['student_number'];?> 
    <input name="student['id']" type="hidden" value="<? echo $row_students['student_number']; ?>" /> 

    <? echo $row_students['student_name'] ; ?>
    <input name="student['assignmentName']" type="hidden" value="<? echo $row_assignments['assignment_name'];?>" /><br/>
    <? }

?>
<br/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
| <a href="index.php">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

and try not to shorthand your code IE   it's just bad practice :D

Comment: Your code won't work properly for multiple records, it will only work for single record. And won't generate the array he wanted. Will always return POST with only one one array